# Using command line to remove text?

Tags: perl, shell, text, command-line

I have a huge file that contains lines that follow this format:

```
New-England-Center-For-Children-L0000392290
Southboro-Housing-Authority-L0000392464
Crew-Star-Inc-L0000391998
Saxony-Ii-Barber-Shop-L0000392491
Test-L0000392334
```

What I'm trying to do is narrow it down to just this:

```
New-England-Center-For-Children
Southboro-Housing-Authority
Crew-Star-Inc
Test
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` likes these things:

```
$ awk -F[/-] -v OFS="-" '{print $(NF-3), $(NF-2)}' file
Special-Restaurant
Eliot-Cleaning
Kennedy-Plumbing
```

This sets `/` and `-` as possible field separators. Based on them, it prints the last_field-3 and last_field-2 separated by the delimiter `-`. Note that `$NF` stands for last parameter, hence `$(NF-1)` is the penultimate, etc.

---

This `sed` is also helpful:

```
$ sed -r 's#.*/(\w*-\w*)-\w*\.\w*</loc>$#\1#' file
Special-Restaurant
Eliot-Cleaning
Kennedy-Plumbing
```

It selects the block `word-word` after a slash `/` and followed with `word.word</loc>` + end_of_line. Then, it prints back this block.

---

## Update

Based on your new input, this can make it:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)-L\w*$/\1/' file
New-England-Center-For-Children
Southboro-Housing-Authority
Crew-Star-Inc
Saxony-Ii-Barber-Shop
Test
```

It selects everything up to the block `-L` + something + end of line, and prints it back.

You can use also another trick:

```
rev file | cut -d- -f2- | rev
```

As what you want is every slice of `-` separated fields, let's get all of them but last one. How? By reversing the line, getting all of them from the 2nd one and then reversing back.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  Will this work if the name is something like 'Test-Test-Test-Test' as well?

Comment: Mmmm I don't know. You'd better update your question indicating all kinds of lines you want to process, because it is based on them that I wrote my answer.

Comment: I just updated the question and I was actually able to narrow it down to make it a bit easier for you :)

Comment: @user3918845 ok! It looks easier now, indeed :) Just updated with two approaches.

Comment: @fedorqui: I thought an awk or sed solution was inappropriate because the question is tagged with only shell and Perl, but since your answer has been accepted it seems that it was the question that was wrong.

Comment: @Borodin thanks for the explanations, I appreciate them. I think sed & awk solutions are not that far from perl, as all can be very related for same jobs. It's not that I posted a solution in Haskell :D I see it is quite common to answer with those tools on perl tags, and to downvote a well formulated, working answer, with long explanations and not providing any comment... sounds a bit weird to me, honestly, moreover when it comes at the time you post your own answer. By the way, my answer [was accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25192848/timeline) way before than your downvote came.

Comment: @fedorqui: I think you are implying that I downvoted your answer so as to gain the upper hand with this question. In fact I no longer compete for reputation points as I get far more out of providing help and getting free experience than I ever did from the points system. In any case I would never resort to downvoting a perfectly good answer just to gain an advantage. But I worry about your level of concern over two reputation points in 44,000. Whether or not I was right to downvote you - and I *am* allowed to make mistakes - I think your preoccupation is more likely to damage you than my vote.

Comment: @Borodin to me downvoting is an extremely useful tool to indicate that an answer is not useful. I tend to use it, or even better commenting it to point out better approaches (if I am able to find them out). That's why I tend to imply that something is wrong in my answer if I get a -1. And that's why I ask the reason of the downvote, moreover when I saw your downvote happening twice under similar circumstances. And no, I don't have much concern about reputation; otherwise, I would spend my time here answering one-liners, instead of looking for duplicates or commenting other answers to learn.

Comment: @fedorqui: I think that, on the whole, we are in agreement. There is no other downvote *"under similar circumstances"*

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F\- 'NF--' OFS=\- file
New-England-Center-For-Children
Southboro-Housing-Authority
Crew-Star-Inc
Saxony-Ii-Barber-Shop
Test
```

- Set the input and output field separator to `-`.
- `NF` contains number of fields. Reduce it by 1 to remove the last field.

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' file
New-England-Center-For-Children
Southboro-Housing-Authority
Crew-Star-Inc
Saxony-Ii-Barber-Shop
Test
```

- Simple greedy regex to match up to the last hyphen.
- In replacement use the captured group and discard the rest.

Comment: Good one, I specially like the sed solution. Very neat and clear!

Answer (score 1):

#### Version 1 of the Question

The first version of the input was in the form of HTML and parts had to be removed both before and after the desired text:

```
$ sed -r 's|.*[A-Z]/([a-zA-Z-]+)-L0.*|\1|' input
Special-Restaurant
Eliot-Cleaning
Kennedy-Plumbing
```

#### Version 2 of the Question

In the revised question, it is only necessary to remove the text that starts with `-L00`:

```
$ sed 's|-L00.*||' input2
New-England-Center-For-Children
Southboro-Housing-Authority
Crew-Star-Inc
Saxony-Ii-Barber-Shop
Test
```

Both of these commands use a single "substitute" command.  The command has the form `s|old|new|`.

Answer (score 1):

The perl code for this would be: `perl -nle'print $1 if(m{-.*?/(.*?-.*?)-})`

We can break the Regex down to matching the following:

- `-` for that's between the city and state
- `.*?` match the smallest set of character(s) that makes the Regex work, i.e. the State
- `/` matches the slash between the State and the data you want
- `(` starts the capture of the data you are interested in
- `.*?-.*?` will match the data you care about
- `)` will close out the capture
- `-` will match the dash before the L####### to give the regex something to match after your data.  This will prevent the minimal Regex from matching 0 characters.

Then the print statement will print out what was captured (your data).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it with Perl:

```
perl -nle 'm{example[.]com/bp/(.*?)/(.*?)-L\d+[.]htm} && print $2' filename
```

Note: the original question was matching input lines like this:

```
<loc>http://www.example.com/bp/Lowell-MA/Special-Restaurant-L0000423916.htm</loc>
<loc>http://www.example.com/bp/Houston-TX/Eliot-Cleaning-L0000422797.htm</loc>
<loc>http://www.example.com/bp/New-Orleans-LA/Kennedy-Plumbing-L0000423121.htm</loc>
```

The -n option tells Perl to loop over every line of the file (but not print them out).

The -l option adds a newline onto the end of every print

The -e 'perl-code' option executes `perl-code` for each line of input

The pattern:

```
/regex/ && print
```

Will only print if the regex matches.  If the regex contains capture parentheses you can refer to the first captured section as $1, the second as $2 etc.

If your regex contains slashes, it may be cleaner to use a different regex delimiter ('m' stands for 'match'):

```
m{regex} && print
```

If you have a modern Perl, you can use -E to enable modern feature and use `say` instead of `print` to print with a newline appended:

```
perl -nE 'm{example[.]com/bp/(.*?)/(.*?)-L\d+[.]htm} && say $2' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very concise in Perl

```
perl -i.bak -lpe's/-[^-]+$//' myfile
```

Note that this will modify the input file *in-place* but will keep a backup of the original data in called `myfile.bak`